# Rails FactoryGirl - Create specific factories in order to meet fk dependancies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

Factories are defined in multiple files under `/factories/` or in the `factories.rb` file

```
spec/factories/*.rb
spec/factories.rb
```

The model customer test needs the `customer` factory. This factory has a foreign key pointing to an `address` factory.

- Address factory is defined in `/spec/factories.rb`
- Customer factory is defined in `spec/factories/customer.rb`

Now if i run

```
rspec spec/model/customer_spec.rb
```

i get the following error

```
postgresql_adapter.rb:602:in `exec_prepared': PG::ForeignKeyViolation:
ERROR:  insert or update on table "customers" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_580b7e1bd8" (ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey)
DETAIL:  Key (address_id)=(1) is not present in table "addresses".
: INSERT INTO "customers" ("date_of_birth", "created_at", "updated_at", , "female_household_members", "male_household_members", "pin_code", "national_id", ) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) RETURNING "id"
```

FactoryGril tries to build the customer factory first and failes because of the missing entry in the address table.

How can i avoid these dependency issues? Can i somehow define to build some basic factories first ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would really be consistent and use one file per factory (model) for consistency. Don't make others dig around.

```
# spec/factories/addresses.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :address do
    # ...
  end
end

# spec/factories/customers.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :customer do
    association :address
    # or the short form
    address
  end
end
```

All you need to do is reference the `address` factory from customer. And [factory_girl will create the associated record](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations).

Comment: Yes of course that was it. I did setup the fk's to fix values for quick testing -.- ... Of course it ended up like this :) The one file per factory is a great tip btw!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding `association :address` to the `customer` factory? It would be easier to help if you showed your `customer` and `address` factories.